# zend autoloading abstract classes

Tags: zend-framework, zend-autoloader

What is the best way to autoload abstract classes

I have a class Formprocessor_Userregistrate extends Formprocessor
Both files are in the same directory, but it cannot find Formprocessor

I already used $autoloader->registerNamespace('Formprocessor_');

When I change the name of Formprocessor into Formprocessor_Formprocessor; I get an "invalid controller" exception

**What is the best technique to load those abstract classes?**

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF convention specifies that you should keep your abstract at the same directory level as the concrete implementations. So, you probably want this:

```
Formprocessor/Userregistrate.php
```

Which would contain:

```
class Formprocessor_Userregistrate extends Formprocessor_Abstract
```

And this:

```
Formprocessor/Abstract.php
```

Which would contain

```
abstract class Formprocessor_Abstract
```

Comment: Do I have to add the keyword "abstract"??? Is that not the same as calling the abstract class FormProcessor_Formprocessor like I try'd already.

Comment: You don't *have* to, no. However, if you're following the ZF coding standard (which is generally a good idea when you're developing ZF applications,) then you should name all abstract classes like *_Abstract.

Comment: I know NOW that "invalid controller" comes from Smarty; some conflict issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your conflict may be due to your shallow level namespaces -- typically, you'd want to prefix all your classes with a global namespace common to all the classes in your app. E.g., instead of Formprocessor_Abstract, you'd have Myapp_Formprocessor_Abstract. (Or whatever...) See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html for more details.